# Saving a file in Db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm really a begginer at programing so ease stuff are hard for me if can anyone explain me or help me in my situation I would apreciate a lot.
On my create method I need to save a file (pdf in db).
What I have now:
Model:

```
public class Candidate : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public IActionResult Post(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    files.CopyTo(stream);
                    //await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        // process uploaded files
        // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
    }
```

In my view i'm using this to attach the file:

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="Index">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
                    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You would need to read about uploading files to a server, You won't get a file "path" there.

Comment: @hardkoded soo what should I do? Remove the file path ?

Comment: You're not going to get a file path to work with. An uploaded file would be in the HTTP request, but you haven't set your action method up to accept that properly. You really should read some tutorials about how to upload files in ASP.NET MVC so you have the general idea, rather than asking someone on Stack Overflow to explain what you need to do.

Comment: @hardkoded can you make like a sample code or link me something that can lead me to do the right way ?

Comment: I think I have found my problem, when I upload the file to Candidate.CV it goes as null, why is that? already tried to debug but nothing

Comment: There are plenty of examples on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're not going to get a file path to work with. An uploaded file would be in the HTTP request, but you haven't set your action method up to accept that properly. You really should read some tutorials about how to upload files in ASP.NET MVC so you have the general idea, rather than asking someone on Stack Overflow to explain what you need to do.
>
> @mason.

This is not a complete answer to your problem but it will show you how file uploading works in asp.net mvc. You will have to modify it according to your problem.

Here’s a form that will post back to the current action.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Here’s the action method that this view will post to which saves the file into a directory in the App_Data folder named “uploads”.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        
   if (file.ContentLength > 0)
   {
       var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
       var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
       file.SaveAs(path);
   }
        
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[Visit this for complete solution](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

**Again** this answer is only to understand how we made HTTP request to upload files and how to save files.

Comment: I'm getting an error on "HttpPostedFileBase"  I'm missing an using reference but System.Web doesnt work

Comment: what using reference should I use

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx System.Web is the referenced lib.

Comment: I'm using asp.net core

Comment: I have edited my code, can u check it out ? the error I'm getting is : Cannot convert form "System.IO.MemoryStream to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile[]